# How do I create HDFS directories that have spaces in them?

Tags: directory, hdfs, naming

Is there a way to create directories in HDFS that have spaces in them? I am attempting to use HDFS to support a tool that uses folders with spaces in them which I do not have the source code for.

I haven't been able to find instructions how to, but I also haven't found documentation stating that it isn't supported.

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS supports special characters in its directory/file name. If the special character in the directory/file name is a non-printable character, you have to pass `-q` option to `dfs -ls` command to print `?` instead.

From HDFS documentation

> Usage: hadoop fs -ls [-C] [-d] [-h] [-q] [-R] [-t] [-S] [-r] [-u]
>
> Options:
>
> - -C: Display the paths of files and directories only.
> - -d: Directories are listed as plain files.
> - -h: Format file sizes in a human-readable fashion (eg 64.0m instead of 67108864).
> - -q: Print ? instead of non-printable characters.
> - -R: Recursively list subdirectories encountered.
> - -t: Sort output by modification time (most recent first).
> - -S: Sort output by file size.
> - -r: Reverse the sort order.
> - -u: Use access time rather than modification time for display and sorting.

Reference: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls

Example:

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir "/tmp/dir with space"
$ bin/hdfs dfs -ls /tmp
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs hadoop          0 2018-09-03 00:57 /tmp/dir with space
$
```